# Predisposition of a person based on day of birth

Tags: sources-mekorot, talmud-gemara, adult-learning

[In a shiur](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4v1X1Ci34h8) by Rabbi Israel Yakobov there was the concept of certain predispositions / inclined character traits of a person based on the specific day (Sunday-Monday) on which they were born mentioned. I remember hearing a short outlook for Tuesday.

What is the source for that concept and could you shortly compromize the ascpects for the other days (or just link a full disclosure)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See [Shabbat 156a](https://www.sefaria.org/Shabbat.156a.7):

> כְּתִיב אַפִּינְקָסֵיהּ דְּרַבִּי יְהוֹשֻׁעַ בֶּן לֵוִי: הַאי מַאן דִּבְחַד בְּשַׁבָּא, יְהֵי גְּבַר וְלָא חֲדָא בֵּיהּ... מַאי טַעְמָא? דְּאִיבְּרוֹ בֵּיהּ אוֹר וָחוֹשֶׁךְ. הַאי מַאן דְּבִתְרֵי בְּשַׁבָּא יְהֵי גְּבַר רַגְזָן. מַאי טַעְמָא? מִשּׁוּם דְּאִיפְּלִיגוּ בֵּיהּ מַיָּא. הַאי מַאן דְּבִתְלָתָא בְּשַׁבָּא — יְהֵי גְּבַר עַתִּיר וְזַנַּאי יְהֵא. מַאי טַעְמָא? מִשּׁוּם דְּאִיבְּרוֹ בֵּיהּ עֲשָׂבִים. הַאי מַאן דִּבְאַרְבְּעָה בְּשַׁבָּא — יְהֵי גְּבַר חַכִּים וְנָהִיר. מַאי טַעְמָא? מִשּׁוּם דְּאִיתְּלוֹ בֵּיהּ מְאוֹרוֹת. הַאי מַאן דִּבְחַמְשָׁה בְּשַׁבָּא — יְהֵי גְּבַר גּוֹמֵל חֲסָדִים. מַאי טַעְמָא? מִשּׁוּם דְּאִיבְּרוֹ בֵּיהּ דָּגִים וְעוֹפוֹת. הַאי מַאן דִּבְמַעֲלֵי שַׁבְּתָא — יְהֵי גְּבַר חַזְרָן. אָמַר רַב נַחְמָן בַּר יִצְחָק: חַזְרָן בְּמִצְוֹת. הַאי מַאן דִּבְשַׁבְּתָא יְהֵי — בְּשַׁבְּתָא יְמוּת, עַל דְּאַחִילוּ עֲלוֹהִי יוֹמָא רַבָּא דְּשַׁבְּתָא. אָמַר רָבָא בַּר רַב שֵׁילָא: וְקַדִּישָׁא רַבָּא יִתְקְרֵי...‏
> ...it was written in Rabbi Yehoshua ben Levi’s notebook: One who was born on the first day of the week, Sunday, will be a person and there will not be one in him...
> What is the reason for this? It is because both light and darkness were created on the first day of Creation.
> One who was born on the second day of the week, Monday, will be a short-tempered person. What is the reason for this? It is because on that day, the second day of Creation, the upper and lower waters were divided...
> One who was born on the third day of the week will be a rich man and a promiscuous person. What is the reason for this? It is because on that day, the third day, vegetation was created...
> One who was born on the fourth day of the week will be a wise and enlightened person. What is the reason for this? It is because the heavenly lights were hung in the heavens on that day...
> One who was born on the fifth day of the week will be a person who performs acts of kindness. What is the reason for this? It is because on that day the fish and fowl were created...
> One who was born on the sixth day of the week will be a seeker. Rav Naḥman bar Yitzḥak said that this means that he will be one who seeks out mitzvot...
> One who was born on Shabbat will die on Shabbat, because they desecrated the great day of Shabbat on his behalf. Rava bar Rav Sheila said: And he will be called a person of great sanctity...

Comment: What does it mean for Sunday : "will be a person and there will not be one in him..."?

Comment: @David the gemara there asks that, see there